# Google place markers infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to place markers on Google Map that captures the coordinates (as shown below). The code is working fine, when clicking on the map I can get markers with infowindow that automatically opened with coordinates info. However, I cannot get the infowindow re-opened after I close it. Thanks!

```js
function placeMarker(position, map) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: map,
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Latitude: ' + position.lat() +
      '<br>Longitude: ' + position.lng()
  });
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
map.addListener('click', function(e) {
  placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
  map.setZoom(9);
  map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
  infowindow.setContent(content);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The InfoWindow won't open after you closed it because you don't add a listener for when you click on your Markers. You are only opening it once, when you create a Marker.

Also it's better to create only 1 InfoWindow object (outside of your `placeMarker` function) and use the `setContent` and `open` methods where necessary, unless you need multiple InfoWindows opened at the same time.

Proof of concept below:

```js
function initMap() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: {
      lat: -28.024,
      lng: 140.887
    }
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  // On map click, create marker
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: e.latLng,
      map: map,
    });
    
    // Set infowindow content and open
    infowindow.setContent(e.latLng.lat() + ', ' + e.latLng.lng());
    infowindow.open(map, marker);

    // On marker click, set infowindow content and open
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

      infowindow.setContent(this.getPosition().lat() + ', ' + this.getPosition().lng());
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  });
}

initMap();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```